# How to remove root element from xml using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Below is the input and expected XML format. I tried a few templates but that is not working.

input XML:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.example.com/mdm/readingxml/2011/07">
  <child1>child1</child1>
  <child2>child2</child2>
  <child3>child3</child3>
  <child4>child4</child4>
</Root>
```

Expected XML:

```
<child1>child1</child1>
<child2>child2</child2>
<child3>child3</child3>
<child4>child3</child4>
```

Used XSLT-:

```
<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for the document element -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried until now

Comment: Thank you @mzjn for your response, Input is coming repetitively from the source so I need to remove the root element and store/concat it into one variable after each iteration, later need to add the same root element.

Comment: Thank you @SiebeJongebloed, i tried <!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for the document element -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: @PeteKirkham The output is an XML fragment and can be easily produced by XSLT without resorting to elaborate hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the root element is very simple. You could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the result will be different from what you expect, because the copied child elements are in the same default namespace as the root element. If you want to move them into no-namespace, you must effectively rename them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result will be an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Hi, It is giving the expected output in xslt but not working after deployemnt instead it is deleting the other elements , i am using this in SOA file adapter and deploying on weblogic server. Thank you

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about your environment.