# How to remove xmlns from the root element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to remove the xmlns from the root element(given below), is there any function or any template that can remove the root template namespace? As you can see below there are multiple namespaces but need to remove only xmlns without prefixes rest two xsd,xsi will be there.
ex-:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.example.com/mdm/readingxml/2011/07" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <child1>child1</child1>
              <child2>child2</child2>
              <child3>child3</child3>
              <child4>child4</child4>
        </Root>
```

Thanks,
Nilesh Jha

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that as with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76859579/how-to-remove-root-element-from-xml-using-xslt), this is NOT a matter of "removing the xmlns" but rather moving ALL the elements to no-namespace + copying the non default namespaces.